# Django template: two different font sizes on same line

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I'd like to be able to render two different font sizes on the same line using a Django template.  Essentially, I'd like the labels to be H6 and the corresponding variable to be standard font size.

Here's my code:

```
    <div> 
        <h5>Details</h5>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h6>Creator By:</h6> {{ order.creator }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <h6>Category:</h6> {{ order.category }}
    </div>
```

This is rendering as follows:

**Details**

**Created By:**

Janice

**Category:**

Automotive

#############################################

Notice that the variables are skipping to a new line.  I would like to render these as follows (on the same line):

**Details**

**Created By:**  Janice

**Category:**  Automotive

Is this just a simple mistake I've made with the HTML?  Or, is there some nuance I'm missing with the Django form?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its about css
The h6 tag have `display: block`
If you want to be side by side you must use

```
<h6 style="display: inline">Creator By:</h6>
```

Comment: I don't want the entire line to be <h6>, only the "Created By" and "Category" labels.  I'd like the variable to be standard font size.

Comment: @equanimity I just tested this answer with Django and it works as expected with an otherwise empty html template, i.e. `<h6 style="display:inline">Creator By:</h6>  {{ order.creator }}`